# How to delete files with multibyte characters in the file name?

Tags: php, ftp

I accidentally created a file with PHP and now I can't delete or re-name it.

The file is called â€%C2%9Dâ2™j299t™93.gif

Edit: I only have access via FTP, the host is Linux based

Edit 2: I can't even delete the directory it is in.

Comment: It might have helped if you'd said what access you have to the system and what operating system it is running.

Comment: And what errors you are seeing and how you are trying to delete it...

Comment: I am trying to delete it through Cyberduck FTP client, the error message is just: Delete operation failed.

Comment: I also tried to unlink it with PHP and nothing happens. The file permissions are 644

Comment: then maybe try to chmod / to chown to your ftp user so you can delete it

Comment: Have you tried simply writing `rm *93.gif`? (if you are the owner, you should have permissions to delete the file)

Comment: Yes rm *.gif, del *.gif, unlink('*.gif'). None works

Answer (score 2):

In the command line, write:

```
ftp to.target.server
del *93.gif
```

If you are the owner of the file, this should work (permissions were 644)

Comment: I am getting this error message: 550 Remove directory operation failed.

Comment: That's because this answer originally used `rm` instead of `del`.  I have corrected it, try again using `del`.

Comment: Even using `del *` I get 550 Delete operation failed.

Comment: The php process and the user you log in with are different. (try this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.unlink.php .. search for the word 'glob') `<?php
   $mask = "*.jpg"
   array_map( "unlink", glob( $mask ) );
?>`

Comment: Thanks but nothing happens klang

Comment: I hate to give up .. can you add some information as to how you made the file in the first place? I still think you have two different users in play here; one that wrote the file and another that tries to delete it (and is denied because of the permissions). To delete the file, you need to do it from php.

Answer (score 0):

From PHP you can use the `unlink` function as follows:

```
<?php
$filename="â€%C2%9Dâ2™j299t™93.gif";

unlink($filename);
?>
```

The problem you have been having is probably to do with the ™ symbol being translated.  If you copy the code above and paste it into your editor and then run it, this should delete the file, assuming it is run from the same directory as the file.

Answer (score 0):

Download Filezilla and set site encoding to enforced utf-8. Then try to delete your file via it.

Comment: The file doesn't appear if I do this

Comment: Why not to ask server admin delete it then?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you don't know the exact filename (as your ftp client does not show it in a proper way). You can iterate thru files. This example deletes all files with the character `%` in it. **Use it carefully**:

```
$d = dir(".");
while (false !== ($entry = $d->read())) {
    if (strpos ($entry, '%') !== false) {
        unlink ($entry);
    }
}
$d->close();
```